# Skip list searching null pointer exception

Tags: java, search, nullpointerexception, skip-lists

I keep seeing null pointer exceptions in my search method for the skip list I'm implementing.

```
public V find(K key, SkiplistMapNode<K,V> header, int level){
    SkiplistMapNode<K,V> N = header;
    for (int i = level-1; i >= 0; i--){
        if ((N != null) && (N.getNext()[i] != null)){
            while (N.getNext()[i].getKey().compareTo(key) < 0){
                N = N.getNext()[i];
            }
        }
    }
    N = N.getNext()[0];
    if ((N != null) && (N.getKey().compareTo(key) == 0)) return N.getValue();
    else return null;
}
```

The line with the exception is:

```
while (N.getNext()[i].getKey().compareTo(key) < 0)
```

I pretty much copied this from [this page](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/~dbelan2/cs251/skip_lists.html) though, so I'm not sure what would be wrong with it.

Comment: What if `N.getNext()`, `N.getNext()[i]` or `N.getNext()[i].getKey()` is null? Try to add more checks.

Comment: Shouldn't checking for `N.getNext()[i]` also be filtering out for `N.getNext()[i].getKey()`? Thanks.

Comment: Nope. Existence of a Container(for your context an array) doesn't imply that the Container has any element(Key).

Comment: Don't copy-paste code you don't understand and don't debug it through stackoverflow.

Comment: Sorry, new to this site. What would be the proper way to get help on this problem then?

Comment: @lullinatalk First off, debug your code. Find out the cause of the NPE. I'm more or less saying: Don't rush to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing that `N.getNext()` advances to the next node, you need to **memorize its value without advancing** if you access the value more than once.

Same with iterator:

```
 while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   if (iterator.next()!=null) {
     iterator.next().toString() // advances to the next item, which may be null
   }
 }
```

Fixed:

```
 while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   Object next=iterator.next(); // advance once
   if (next!=null) { // check value
     next.toString() // use same value, without advancing
   }
```

}

It's hard to tell from your code where you really want to advance to the next element, and where you need the elements values again. Store the next value in a variable, and check and use this value afterwards, same as in the Iterator example above.

Answer (score 0):

If you access an objects method, you should really make sure that the object isn't null.  In your case, in...

```
while (N.getNext()[i].getKey().compareTo(key) < 0)
```

These...

```
N.getNext()  //the only really important one you seem not to be checking
N.getNext()[i]
```

could be null and should be checked and possibly even (though less likely and debatably)

```
N
N.getNext()[i].getKey()
key
```

Comment: The OP has already checked first two level. Third level is proposed in the comment. The problem with this question is that it doesn't qualify for being proper, as it has no clear indication of OP's claim

Comment: The only one really needed to be checked in the code as it stands is N.getNext() but I was trying to be complete in my answer. I've been a little short in the past.

Comment: I tried including all 4 of these and still got a null pointer exception. I'm starting to think it's a problem somewhere else in the class. Thanks though.

Comment: Yes. I'll just try to figure out what else I might be doing wrong.

Comment: The only other thing that could be null on that line is 'key' but that could throw a NullPointerError in a different location but include this line further down the stack trace